# Trying to get "nearest" result in query from a table representing a grid

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores a grid with x, y and elevation.  I have some known elevations and a lot of empty (NULL) elevations.  I'm trying to build a query that interpolates (simple linear interpolation) the missing values, but I'm stuck way at the beginning: I can't even write a query that gets the nearest non-null value.  What I wanted to do was use a sub query that referenced the outer query, but that doesn't work ("unknown column" error).

Here's what I tried, but this doesn't work

```
SELECT tg.*, tx.elevation FROM `temp_grid` tg
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT xGrid, yGrid, elevation
FROM temp_grid 
WHERE elevation IS NOT NULL
AND yGrid > tg.yGrid
ORDER BY yGrid
LIMIT 1
) ti ON tg.xGrid=ti.xGrid
WHERE tg.elevation IS NULL
```

I've been wracking my brain trying to think of how to do this with joins and group by, but can't come up with anything... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a subquery in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT tg.*,
       (SELECT elevation
        FROM temp_grid tg2
        WHERE elevation IS NOT NULL AND
              tg2.yGrid > tg.yGrid
        ORDER BY tg2.yGrid
        LIMIT 1
       ) as elevation
FROM `temp_grid` tg
WHERE tg.elevation IS NULL;
```

For the rest of your problem, you just need to change the `where` and `order by` in the subquery to calculate the distance between two points, in the direction you are interested in.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that (subquery in the select with that sort of implied join).  It turned out to be painfully slow, even when I added indexes on the xGrid and yGrid, but thanks!  (I solved my problem by loading the whole table into memory and doing it there... then the UPDATE statements take forever, but oh well...)